# css свойство attr

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Такой вопрос в html есть некий блок в котором находится например 6 дочерних, 4 из которых имеют свойство data-a, мне надо вытянуть данные из этого свойства, и закинуть в html, по средствам css content: attr(), в дальнейшем я вкидываю до блока задаю им padding и цвет 
Но проблема в том, что 2 элемента не имеют этого свойства, но оно у них берется и делает им цвет и padding, получается просто некрасивый кубик без информации.

Вариант добавить еще класс в html не подходит, сам html каркас трогать нельзя

```
.block:after{
content: attr(data-a);
color: white;
background-color: red;
padding: 2px 8px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
top: -105px;
left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: выбрать нужные элементы через nth-child

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Только для элементов с атрибутом `data-a`:

```
.block[data-a]:after{
  content: attr(data-a);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)